# paypal donation button with FIXED amount

Tags: url, paypal

here is the paypal url to make a donation to my site :

```
<a style="text-align: -webkit-auto;" href="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&amp;hosted_button_id=000000000" target="_blank"><img class="alignright" title="Paypal_bouton" alt="" src="http://www.mysite.com/cms/wp-content/uploads/Paypal_bouton.jpg" width="123" height="39" /></a>
```

is it possible to add a parameter to the URL to pre-fill the amout to 10$, 25$ and 50$ for three different URL button ?

Comment: not really sure that I understand your question,
but you cannot have dropdown options for donation button.

Comment: The question is : how to pass the donation amount from the paypal url ?

Comment: For 3 different amount of donation i can do 3 different button, but is it possible to make ONE button and send the amount as a variable in the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try non-hosted button:

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_donations&business=S4X5XW328WAYY&lc=US&item_name=tests&currency_code=USD&amount=10.00

You can pass your own amount in the `amount` variable.

Click [here](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_donations&business=S4X5XW328WAYY&lc=US&item_name=tests&currency_code=USD&amount=10.00)